# Can't get the searchValue, orderColumn, orderDirection that passed from the AJAX into my API controllers

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, datatable, server-side

So, in order to obtain thousands of data sets and fetch data using ajax, I'm attempting to integrate datatable server-side in my APIs.

Here's my API's code

```
[HttpGet("GetServerData")]
        public ActionResult GetServerData(int draw, int start, int length, string searchValue, string orderColumn, string orderDirection)
        {
            var query = _context.Products.AsQueryable();

            //Apply filtering based on searchValue
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchValue));
            }

            // Apply sorting
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderColumn) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderDirection))
            {
                // Assuming orderColumn is a valid property name
                var propertyInfo = typeof(Product).GetProperty(orderColumn);
                if (propertyInfo != null)
                {
                    query = orderDirection == "asc"
                        ? query.OrderBy(p => propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null))
                        : query.OrderByDescending(p => propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null));
                }
            }

            // Count the total number of records before paging
            int totalRecords = query.Count();

            // Apply paging
            query = query.Skip(start).Take(length);

            var records = query.ToList();

            var response = new
            {
                draw,
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                recordsFiltered = totalRecords, // You might modify this based on your filtering logic
                data = records
            };

            return Ok(response);
        }
```

and here's my AJAX request,

```
"ajax": {
            url: "https://localhost:7174/API/products/GetServerData",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (d) {
                d.draw = d.draw || 1;
                d.start = d.start || 0;
                d.length = d.length || 10; // Records per page
                d.search = d.search || {};
                d.search.value = d.search.value || '';
                var order = d.order[0] || {};
                d.orderColumn = order.column || '';
                d.orderDirection = order.dir || '';
                d.searchValue = d.search.value || ''; // Ensure that searchValue is included
            },
            dataSrc: "data"
        },
```

This is what the error appeared

> {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One
> or more validation errors
> occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-245b7bb81d09c2a78a230e2a25c28a19-90e9f86d60626f3b-00","errors":{"orderColumn":["The
> orderColumn field is required."],"searchValue":["The searchValue field
> is required."],"orderDirection":["The orderDirection field is
> required."]}}

My AJAX code cannot read the searchValue, orderColumn, or orderDirection values, hence they cannot be passed to the API.

is there any suggestion?

Comment: You cannot with Entity (_context),  Entity you use Migration to create a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  Normally Entity is run only when the c# classes change.  You ajax code is using JSON for the body of the request and do not have any c# classes for Entity to use.

Comment: 400 error is related with the parameter inside the request, could you pls show us the request content?

Comment: if the ajax code can't know those values, just send defaults.  But why?  Seems like those would be standard controls on the page that you could pass into the ajax call, or read from the DOM.  btw, the data should be name/value pairs...  they're queryvars.

Comment: could we get the required parameter value before sending the ajax request?

Comment: hi pal, thanks for reach my question, appreciate it. 
https://www.imagebam.com/view/MEOKZB3
@TinyWang the required parameter are this searchValue, orderColumn, orderDirection

Comment: Hi, the request content I mean is the payload and the request header in browser F12 network blade... I want to see if the client sent the correct value to the backend

Comment: https://www.imagebam.com/view/MEOL998  you can check from there mates @TinyWang . what i attach is when i can request the data without required parameter, because if insist to put the parameter there, error appeared. i'm looking for how can i applied the search box, order, etc to my data which implement datatables server-side

Comment: in my sample below, if I sent the ajax request, I will get request url like `https://localhost:7041/home/GetServerData?start=1&length=2&searchVaule=asdf`, which is corresponding to my action method `public IActionResult GetServerData(int start, int length, string searchValue)`. In your scenario, you have action method `public ActionResult GetServerData(int draw, int start, int length, string searchValue, string orderColumn, string orderDirection)` which should receive `draw, start, lenght, searchVaule, orderColumn, orderDirection` 6 parameters in total, but your request sent from the browser

Comment: consists plenty of parameters which doesn't match the parameters you defined in your controller action method. I'm afraid you are trying to do something else.... and the mismatch led the 400 error occurred. You might try to test in browser with url `https://localhost:7174/API/products/GetServerData?draw=1&vstart=0&length=5&searchVaule=hello&orderColumn=colcum&orderDirection =desc` and see if the API is triggered. Then, if the request format is what you want, change your ajax code, if this is not what you want, change the input parameter in your action method please.

Answer (score 0):

I have a test with code like below, I think we could get the required parameters before sending ajax request. to avoid the situation that we fail to get the parameters.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetServerData(int start, int length, string searchValue) {
     string a = "{\"res\":\"success\",\"searchValue\":\""+ searchValue + "\"}";
     return Ok(a);
}

$("#GetServerData").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
         url: "https://localhost:7041/home/GetServerData",//?length=10&start=0&searchValue=keywords
         type: "get",
         dataType: "json",
         data:{
                    start:1,
                    length:2,
                    searchValue:"asdf"
         },
         success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.res);
         }
    })
})
```

No matter whether I put data in url or in `data` they all become query string and append to the url finally. Could you pls help check the request in your side?

[image]